# How to use openstack API v3 to list accessible volumes

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

I am learning OpenStack now and I want to list all accessible volumes on my OpenStack controller by HTTP get request with x_auth_token:

http://{OpenStack controller IP}:8776/v3/{project_id}/volumes

(Reference URL: https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/block-storage/v3/index.html?expanded=#list-accessible-volumes)

But, the request body always as below:

```html
    {
    "badRequest":{
    "message": "Malformed request url",
    "code": 400
    }
}
```

I have try many times but they all didn't work.
So, I want to know, what the request url should be here?
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: The first step is diagnosing API problems should be to run one of the existing command line clients in `--debug` mode.  This will show you the exact requests that the client is making (so, run `cinder --debug list`).

Comment: I run 'cinder --debug list', but it didn't show the information I really understand, are there other things I can try to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons is that your **project_id** is incorrect or doesn't match your **credential**, take a look at this [link](https://github.com/openstack/cinder/blob/master/cinder/api/openstack/wsgi.py#L895). In order to solve this problem you can:
1. Try openstack command with debug option.

```
openstack --debug volume list
#or
cinder --debug list
```

you could get the request and response details:

```
REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://ip:port/v3/{project_id}/volumes/detail -H "User-Agent: python-cinderclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {token_value}"
```

Make sure you have input every required headers(context-type/x-auth-token/...).

2. Try to ask for help in irc channel **#openstack-cinder**